# Unable to install microsoft -edge-dev on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, lubuntu, dependencies

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo apt install microsoft-edge-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 microsoft-edge-dev : Depends: libatomic1 (>= 4.8) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo apt install libatomic1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libatomic1 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8-20180414-1ubuntu2) but 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ neofetch
        #####           lubuntu@lubuntu 
       #######          --------------- 
       ##O#O##          OS: Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 20200604 x86_64 
       #######          Host: HP Slimline Desktop PC 270-p0XX 
     ###########        Kernel: 5.3.0-28-generic 
    #############       Uptime: 10 days, 2 hours, 13 mins 
   ###############      Packages: 1093 
   ################     Shell: bash 4.4.20 
  #################     Resolution: 1440x900 
#####################   DE: LXDE 
#####################   WM: Openbox 
  #################     Theme: Adwaita [GTK3] 
                        Icons: Adwaita [GTK3] 
                        Terminal: lxterminal 
                        Terminal Font: Monospace 10 
                        CPU: Intel i3-7100 (4) @ 3.900GHz 
                        GPU: Intel HD Graphics 630 
                        Memory: 2167MiB / 3829MiB

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 20200604
Release:    18.04.4
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Comment: Your details provided in the `neofetch` output don't match a *supported* Ubuntu system; matching instead an off-topic Ubuntu based system instead.   Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: yes ..The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libatomic1 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8-20180414-1ubuntu2) but 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: @karel please post your comment as answer, it resolves the issue for my 22.04 LTS

Comment: @SayyedDawood If the above link (2 comments above this comment) answered your question please click the "Yes" option to the right of "Does this answer your question?" in the light blue banner above your question. This will single-handedly close your question as a duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa).

Comment: @karel I am sorry I could not find that option as might be I did not post this Question. I tried to flag it as duplicate but could not.

Comment: Usually it works, but this time it didn't. Maybe it's a site bug.